# Saving, reading, exchanging own file format?

Tags: iphone, xml, file-io, document, file-format

any recommendations for saving four strings into an own file format that is read by the application and can be shared?

In my app, you will be able to enter some text in some boxes and the app shows a view with an background image and those strings. Now, I am already able to save this as a picture, but I actually want to save it to an own file format so that you can save different files that can be modified afterwards as well or even exchanged via email and opened from another iphone with the app.

Now, I wrote the code for accessing the documents folder of the app, as well as saving and deleting. Thing is, i dont know how to store those strings in a file (perhaps in a xml?) and read them easily afterwards from my application.

For the exchanging part, I found that link which would be a nice feature indeed: http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

Parsing xml seems not that difficult (never done it before): http://ipad.about.com/od/iPad-App-Dev/a/How-To-Parse-Xml-Files-In-Xcode-Objective-C.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys I found that very nice method in the NSString documentation:

–writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:

I think I am gonna separate my strings by /n and save them to a .txt. When I am gonna read the file afterwards, i am getting the string, divide it to substrings. That will do it, I guess.

One last question: Is it possible to replace the content of my file so that I won't need to create a new file every time i want to change something?

Thanks!

Comment: I thought writeToFile would add something to the content. Apparently, it replaces the content. I am just gonna go with it.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only a small bit of infomation then the easiest way to store your data in a file would be using a plist - there's a good tutorial here - http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/02/14/loading-data-from-plist-files/

Comment: Is the pList exchangeable? Thanks for your answer though!

Comment: It's just an XML file - exchange it with whatever you want!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the plist, you could also do the following approaches:
1) simplest - open a file in your documents directory, write the 4 strings (using whatever delimiter/end of string marker is useful - carriage return?) and overwrite them each time through. (i.e. it's your file, you can format it how you like)
2) mildly harder - use Apple's NSArchive to pack and unpack the strings.
3) possible overkill - store them directly in a SQLite database
4) major overkill - store them in CoreData.

Of course, the "overkill" options also provide you with extra features which may be of use if your app functionality extends beyond what you've outlined.

By sharing, I would think that simple copy and paste might be enough, but there's also sending it via email, or tripping another app's URL scheme to make it open it and sending the strings as part of the URL.  You'd have to know that the other app would be able to interpret your strings as part of the URL, so you might have to write it yourself.

Comment: What do you mean by "file"? xml with my own ending, like, stuff.myformat instead of stuff.xml?

Comment: No, I meant for your end of string marker.  If you just write the contents of 4 strings in a file, there's no way to know where one ends and the other begins unless you mark them.  Traditionally, C strings use a null character \0 to mark them, but these are not automatic with NSStrings.  This is assuming you're not using xml, because it sounds like you only want to write 4 strings and read them in later.

Comment: And I can just define the type? Like its an xml but the file ending is stuff.bla? Thing is that i need to share the file via email. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The question is: What are you sharing it with? Good programming would say to use a proper extension that describes the data inside the file, i.e. if it's an XML file, then use .xml.  But if it's a text file with just 4 strings, it could be .txt.  The point being, it's your file and you can do what you want with it, given the limitation that you need to share with other programs via email, who'll have to know what it is.